# Change Android App starting activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the start up activity.
I created an activity when the app loads but I want to add a screen before that, I'm not sure where to change the Android manifest to load a certain layout/activity when the app starts.

Answer (score 2):

The startup activity [Launcher Activity] is declared in the projects' AndroidManifest.xml file

Look for that activity tag in the manifest which looks like this

```
<activity android:name=".Main"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Look at the attribute android:name. Main is the class which is launched when the app starts. Currently your calendar activity name should be there. Change that to the .classpath of your activity that you want to launch.

That should do it. You may also want to do the hello world application in the tutorials and go through the docs a little to see how Android Applications work.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489248/how-to-change-the-startup-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Just create another activity and set it as Launcher Activity and after a timer (if that's your achieve) just call the other activity!